# exoplayer cast extension set referer in header

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, google-cast-sdk

I'm using cast extension with exoplayer2 `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-cast:2.11.7'`.
How i can set custom header parameters like `Referer` like we set with `DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that with cast API but can do with custom receiver check here
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4760

Also check here for creating custom receiver
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/core_features#drm